# How to best link to an API controller

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-web-api, resharper

To link to `Controller/A/<anId>` I do this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(anId, "Action", "Controller", new {id = anId})
```

Action is underlined by Resharper and I can navigate to it with F12.

But I have a link to an api controller:

```
@Html.ActionLink("API Version", "../api/controller/", new {id = anId})
```

This does not have a resharper navigation option and is not going to refactored if I rename the controller. Is there a cleaner way to link to an APIController from a razor view? Particularly one Resharper recognises.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually have to update the api routes, because api by default does not include an action.

So add this route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

You can then create a link like so:

```
@Url.RouteUrl("ActionRoute", new {httproute= "", controller = "controller", action = "action"});
```

***EDIT***

I re-read your question and it doesn't say anything about an action, so I just assumed that, either way, you can still use `@Url.RouterUrl`:

```
@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new {httproute= "", controller = "controller"});
```

Comment: Good answer.  Note the typo for RouteParameter (not RouterParameter).

Answer (score 8):

As other answers have suggested already, you can use the `Url.RouteUrl` like so:

```
@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new {httproute= "", controller = "MyApiController"});
```

You can also use the shortcut method `Url.HttpRouteUrl` instead like so:

```
@Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "MyApiController" })
```

`"DefaultApi"` is the default Route name when creating a new WebApi project. This string should match whatever name you gave your HttpRoute in the `WebApiConfig.cs` file.

Both of these solutions will only help you generate the URL to the route, they won't actually generate an HTML link for you. You need to use them like this:

```
<a href="@Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "MyApiController" })">My Link Text</a>
```

If you want Razor to generate the HTML anchor tag for you, you can use this method instead:

```
@Html.RouteLink("My Link Text", "DefaultApi", new { controller = "MyApiController" })
```

This method provides a very similar interface to `@Html.ActionLink` which is used for regular Controller/Action links.

All of these solutions allow click-through to work with ReSharper.

Comment: I like this solution as it eliminates the need for the explicit httproute = "" parameter.

Comment: @Html.RouteLink() not giving the proper url. I have checked it in MVC 5

Answer (score 3):

I dunno about Resharper but you could do this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "API Version", 
    "Action", 
    "Controller", 
    new { id = anId, httproute = "" },
    null
)
```

If you pass `httproute = ""`, the helper will generate an url to your API controller using its routing definitions.

Comment: I had to use an alternative overload (please review edit), but the link I get is `http://localhost:64404/Controller/Action/anId` No mention of `api`.

Comment: When I used it as you say, I get link `http://localhost:64404/source/Action?Length=10`

Comment: Closest so far: ` @Html.ActionLink("API Version", null, new { id = Model.Id.Name, httproute = "" })` yields: `http://localhost:64404/api/controller/anId?action=detail`

Comment: See my updated answer. I took by mistake the wrong overload shown in your question.